# ActiveMQ Artemis ClientID not being set

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm having a hard time setting the Client ID on my consumers in ActiveMQ Artemis.

I'm using Spring to create the `ConnectionFactory` and `ContainerFactory` and then using it to set the `ClientID`. For some reason it does not appear on the Artemis Console.

Here is the code defining the factory beans on my configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory myConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(host);
    connectionFactory.setUser(user);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);

    // I have tried setting it here
    connectionFactory.setClientID("myClient");
    connectionFactory.setGroupID("myClient");
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myContainerFactory(@Qualifier("myConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                 DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setRecoveryInterval(10000);

    // I have tried setting it here
    factory.setClientId("myClient");
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

And here is the code where I create a bunch of listeners according to a `ListerEnum`:

```
  for (ListersEnum listener : ListenersEnum.values()) {

        IListener handler = BeanUtil.getBean(listener.getHandler());
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = BeanUtil.getBean<DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory>(listener.getContainerFactory());

        SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
        endpoint.setId(listener.getId());

        endpoint.destination = listener.getQueue();
        endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> handler.onReceive(message));

        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = containerFactory.createListenerContainer(endpoint);

        // I have tried setting it here also
        messageListenerContainer.setClientId("myClient");

        endpoint.setupListenerContainer(messageListenerContainer);

        jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(endpoint, containerFactory);

        messageListenerContainer.start();
  }
```

And then on the Artemis Console, there is no Client ID set:

[image: Artemis screenshot]

Besides that, I have noticed the `Creation Time` on the console is updated each second. Like the connection is being refresh every time. Is this normal behavior? Does it have anything to do with the client ID?

My dependencias are:

```
springBootVersion = '1.5.15.RELEASE'

compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-commons:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:1.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-selector:1.4.0'
```

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

I have changed my `myContainerFactory` to:

```
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myContainerFactory(@Qualifier("myConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                             DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setRecoveryInterval(10000);

    // I have tried setting it here
    factory.setClientId("myClient");

    // Commented this so Spring wont set its default values
    // configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    return factory;
}
```

Then I started getting

```
2019-01-24 17:50:28.612 ERROR 25504 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TEST_QUEUE' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=9, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Client id has already been set
```

I tried hacking it by making my ClientID like `"myClient" + new Date().getTime()` but got the same result. The strange part is that if I remove the `clientId` altogether, on the artemis console I only see one connection... So how it is trying to create another ones with the same client id? Any ideas?

**Edit 2**

I made an example outside of Spring to see if this would be a Spring problem... But it doesn't seem so. I got the same results: The client ID does not show on the console and if I set it on the `Connection` I get the `Client ID already set` error. Can it be something about my artemis console...? I'm using `Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.2`. Please halp :s

Heres the code in case anyone want to try:

```
import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Consumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {

        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisCf = null;

        try {
            artemisCf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616?retryInterval=1000reconnectAttempts=-1",
                    "user", "pass");
            artemisCf.setRetryInterval(1000);
            artemisCf.setReconnectAttempts(-1);
            artemisCf.setClientID("TESTE");

            factory = (ConnectionFactory) artemisCf;

            connection = factory.createConnection();

            // If I uncomment this I get the "Client id has already been set" error
            // connection.setClientID("TESTE");

            session = connection.createSession(true, 2);

            Queue queue = session.createQueue("QUEUE.TESTE.CONNCETION");

            consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

            consumer.setMessageListener(new Listener("Me"));

            connection.start();

            Thread.sleep(2000000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (consumer != null && session != null && connection != null) {
                consumer.close();
                session.close();
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Listener implements MessageListener {

        private String listenerName;

        public Listener(String consumerName) {
            this.listenerName = consumerName;
        }

        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            try {
                System.out.println(listenerName + " received " + textMessage.getText());
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I deleted my previous answer because I went back and looked at the way the Artemis console works, and it does look at the core client session's meta-data to get the value of the client ID so it should be showing up.

Comment: Will try this ASAP, but im not so confident because if I remove the client ID, I only see one coonection being created... So it shouldn't be creating more than one when I have the the client id... Will get back soon! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JustinBertram didn't work the `randomUUID()` :/ I noticed it is all about setting the `clientID` at the `ConnectionFactory`. If I set it there I get the error. If I set in the other places (containerfactory, listener, etc) it doesnt give any error but the client ID is not set on Artemis Console

Comment: @JustinBertram please check my edit 2. I think you may reproduce easily now if you need!

Comment: I just ran a test using a durable subscriber with the client ID set on the connection factory and it showed up in the web console. Were you using the 2.6.2 client?

Comment: You mean `org.apache.activemq:artemis-core-client`? I'm using `1.4.0` for I think is the newest one using Java 7. Can you test without a durable subscriber as well please?

Comment: I mean, in the example outside spring I posted I'm using `org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:5.12.0`. I'm really starting to think is something about my Artemis installation... D:

Comment: I tested using a non-durable subscriber and it worked fine. I tested with the Artemis 1.4.0 client as well as the 2.6.2 client. I did *not* test with the ActiveMQ 5.x client. Your code wouldn't work with that client since you're using an Artemis implementation class (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`).

Comment: @Justin I will try with those clients... But my code does wotk with the ActiveMQ 5.x client. It's literally the only dependency in my `pom.xml` o.O

Comment: If your code works with the ActiveMQ 5.x client you must have changed the bit that was relying on the Artemis implementation class.

Comment: @JustinBertram you were right... I was looking at another POM when I told you about the `activemq-all`. Anyway I tried using both `1.4.0` and `2.6.2` and same results... ClientID not shown... It has to be something about my Artemis broker then :s
Will try reinstaling it, or creating another broker... I have simply followed the oficial tutorial to install it: https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/running-server.html... Will tweek around, thank you very much